# Would somebody be kind enough to tell how to setup Amazon SES with namecheap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I manage to figure out how to get my DKIMs and SPF from amazon ses, but I don't know how to set it up on namecheap?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not a 'programming question,' possibly server admin-related, but I don't imagine Server Fault would want it. Possibly [SU], or [webapps.SE]?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Login to your namecheap account, then under `Host Management > All Host Records` we need to add our DKIM and Domain record Verification Set under the sub-domain settings. The values take this form:

```
Host Name            IP Address/URL              Record Type     TTL
name1._domainkey     value1.dkim.amazonses.com.  CNAME (Alias)   1800
name2._domainkey     value2.dkim.amazonses.com.  CNAME (Alias)   1800
name3._domainkey     value3.dkim.amazonses.com.  CNAME (Alias)   1800
_amazonses           someDomainRecordSet         TXT Record      1800
```

Do take note of the following changes:

Instead of `name1._domainkey.test.com` we changed it to `name1._domainkey` . Yes, it's intentional. There is no need for the domain test.com at the end of the line.

Also we removed `test.com` from `_amazonses.test.com` as namecheap's dns will append it upon save.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yep, it clearly explains this process for me. It only took a couple of minutes for me to get it propagated & listed correctly for my domain.

Comment: Is the dot at the end of 'value1.dkim.amazonses.com.' on purpose? Or dit it get truncated and it should say 'value1.dkim.amazonses.com.www.example.com'

Comment: The instructions in this answer worked for me.  However, I needed to delete the domain in the Amazon SES console and start again

Comment: If you're using a sub-domain (i.e. app.example.com ) for the _amazonses you will need to add the sub-domain part since namecheap will only add the main domain. So, instead of just _amazonses, put _amazonses.app.  This worked for me.

Comment: I tried this as well. The TXT record shows up with nslookup but remains in pending verification on AWS console. What could be wrong?

Comment: @BringBackCommodore64 the dot is on purpose and worked for me.

Comment: @ElesinOlalekanFuad My own text record value had an equals sign (=) at the end of it that I missed when I did double-click, copy, and paste. I didn't catch it until my verification failed after three days. Always worth a quick double check.

Comment: Note that the host name should match the SES identity so if you're verifying www.test.com then your host is name1._domainkey.www but if you are verifying test.com (no www) then your host is name1._domainkey